# Window.getSelection() onchange not working

Tags: javascript, html, selection, onchange

I am trying to call a function when the selected text on a website changes.

Right now nothing happens:

```
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<script>    
var selection = null;

window.getSelection().toString().addEventListener('change', function() {
    selection = window.getSelection().toString();
  alert(selection);
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can't listen to a string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/onselectionchange

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
 document.onselectionchange = () => {

     let text = window.getSelection().toString();

     console.log(text)

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[`document.onselectionchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/onselectionchange)** that will be fired if the `selectionchange`, like :

```js
document.onselectionchange = function() {
  console.log(window.getSelection().toString());
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```